# jQuery Code works in index.html but not in index.php / wordpress theme files

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am new to coding, especially javascript and jQuery and hope you can help me with something. I am creating a WP theme, so everything I am coding is coded in WP files. I often made the experience that code that works perfectly fine in an index.html does not work in my WP theme files and I haven't really figured out why yet... So here is the most current example:

My front page is divided into 3 sections using divs. In the third section/div I want to load different divs based on which button is clicked. So basically, when Button 1 is clicked, the corresponding div1 content is shown and the others are being hidden. And when Button 2 is clicked, the corresponding div2 content is visible and the other divs are hidden. I need a total of four buttons/links and 4 corresponding divs with different content.

I found a code using jQuery on codepen that does almost exactly what I need function wise. (See code below or here is the link: https://codepen.io/whattodrink/pen/myPGpm). When I copied & pasted this code into my html.index files, everything works fine as it does in the codepen. But when I copy and paste the same code into my wordpress theme files, the jQuery does not work anymore. I read that in WP you cannot use $, so I changed all instances to jQuery. But this isn't working either. Can anyone help me as to why that is?

When I inspect this in Chrome, I get the following error twice:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of index.js:1 404 (Not Found)"

I tested if jQuery loads in my WP files with a simple code from w3schools and it does work, so it should be correctly added to my WP theme.

Here is now the code:

HTML:

```
  <a href="#" class="button">
    Button 1
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    Button 2
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    Button 3
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    Button 4
  </a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="content-1 active">Jana 1 Content</div>
  <div class="content-2">Button 2 Content</div>
  <div class="content-2">Button 3 Content</div>
  <div class="content-2">Button 4 Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {
  background-color:red;
}

.content {
  margin-top:30px;
}

div[class*="content-"] { 
  display:none;
}

div.active { 
  display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.button').first().addClass('active');

jQuery('.button').click(function(){
  var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
  jQuerysiblings = jQuerythis.parent().children(),
  position = jQuerysiblings.index(jQuerythis);
  console.log (position);

  jQuery('.content div').removeClass('active').eq(position).addClass('active');

  jQuerysiblings.removeClass('active');
  jQuerythis.addClass('active');
})
```

how I added it to my WP theme:

```
<?php

function lux_files() {
 wp_register_script( "index", plugins_url( "index.js", __FILE__), array( "jquery"));
 wp_enqueue_script ( "index");
 wp_enqueue_script( "javascript", get_template_directory_uri() . '/index.js', array(), false );
 wp_enqueue_style("font-awesome", "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 wp_enqueue_style("google-fonts", "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Raleway:400,700&display=swap");
 wp_enqueue_style("main_styles", get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lux_files');



function lux_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lux_features');

?>
```

Comment: First, try wrapping your jQuery code around $(function () {  // Your jQuery code here });

Comment: @SleekGeek Thanks SO much! That worked!! Do I need to wrap all my jQuery code in this in order to make it work in WP??  Also, I would have another question regarding that same code. Not sure if I should open a new question? The way this is written right now, the entire page gets reloaded and that way brings me back to the beginning of my front page (div / section 1) instead of div / section 3. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes. I am gonna add my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that the document is ready before running your jQuery code. To do that, do the following:

```
$(function () { 

// Your jQuery code here 

});
```